# How dynamicaly change header of dataTable jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to change a title of my table genrated thanks to plugin datatables jQuery

Do you know if I can do something like this :

```
table.title(0).text("new header")
```

?

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
$('#my-table').dataTable( {
    "sDom": '<"mytitle">frtip'
});

$("div.mytitle").html('new header');
```